# About the uniqueness of a quadric determined by sufficient points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadrics

What is the condition on a set of 14 points for them to *uniquely* determine a quadric in $\mathbb{P}^4$? Is being in *linear* general position enough to guarantee uniqueness? If not, what is the alternative condition? In what precise sense of "general position" must the points be in general position?

What if I know that the quadric is non-singular? If I pick 14 points from the intersection of two non-singular quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$, can they be in general position?

Thank you.